# Bean scanning for Spring Boot in IntelliJ

Tags: unit-testing, annotations, spring-boot, autowired

I am using Spring Boot to create a micro service, and all is well, except for a couple of minor annoyances.

Autowiring in my test classes, I am getting the following warnings on @Autowired annotations:

> Autowired members must be defined in the valid spring
>   bean(@Component/@Service,etc.) Checks that auto wired members are
>   defined in valid Spring bean (@Component|@Service|...).

this is using the following test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class MyRecordTest {

    public static final String NUMBER = "ABC/123456";

    @Autowired
    private MyFactory factory;

    @Autowired
    private Marshaller marshaller;

    ...
}
```

where my Application configuration class is defined as

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Marshaller getMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.my.classes");
        return marshaller;
    }
}
```

and MyFactory has the @Component annotation:

```
@Component
public class MyFactory {
    ...
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Also, standing out like a sore thumb, the only uncovered line in my application is the SpringApplication.run line in the public static void main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

How can I get this covered or ignored?

Comment: I believe it's because: `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` or `@RunWith` doesnt have @Component inside the annotation. You could use `@SpringBootTest`

Answer (score 0):

As Anand stated, you need the following on your test for the dependencies to be autowired in tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

Like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyRecordTest {

    public static final String NUMBER = "ABC/123456";

    @Autowired
    private MyFactory factory;

    @Autowired
    private Marshaller marshaller;

    ...
}
```

Comment: @Xetius did this answer your question?